# Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{}\infty}{f_n(x_n)=f(x)}$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Hello I have problems with this exercise

Let $F$ be a sequence of continuous functions in a metric space $(M; d)$ that converges uniformly to a
function $f$. Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{}\infty}{f_n(x_n)=f(x)}$ for all sequence $\{ x_n \}$ of points in $M$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow{x}$

I need a hint

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
|f_n(x_n) - f(x)|
= |\left( f_n(x_n)-f(x_n) \right) + \left( f(x_n) - f(x) \right)|
\leq |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| + |f(x_n) - f(x)|
$$